# Pushing boolean values of an array to uint8 bitfield

Tags: c, bit-fields

Let's suppose I have:

```
myArray[7] = {TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE}

uint8 mybitfield;
```

What is the most efficient way to "push" those values to an uint8 bitfield with `0=FALSE`, `1=TRUE`

So that *mybitfield* is represented as:

```
[1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0]
```

(The Least Significant Bit is not considered and will be always 0).

Thanks!

Comment: sorry. it was a mistake. Have corrected it now

Comment: There's really no way besides a loop and setting bits in `mybitfield`. That's because individual bits can't be addressed.

Comment: Order of bits is ambigious. Is `myArray[0]` bit 1 or bit 7? (Assuming LSB is bit 0)

Comment: Had corrected now the order. So myArray[0] is the Most Significant Bit. In the example above it is the "1"

Comment: Ironically C is the preferred language for embedded, while not even having the concept of bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already noted, you have to iterate over the bits individually, for example:

```
int myArray[7] = {TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE};

uint8_t bitfield = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
    bitfield |= myArray[i] ? 1 : 0;
    bitfield <<= 1;
}
```

This results in `0b10011000`, i.e., the array has the most significant bit first and an implicit zero for the least significant bit.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  I'm interested to know what operation is needed if I want to set the last element of array as the Most Significant bit in this case?

Comment: @JohnDoe Iterate over the array in reverse order. Or remove the `<<= 1` shift, and instead shift the bit you set, i.e., `bitfield |= (myArray[i] ? 1U : 0U) << i`.

Comment: (You can also remove the ternary operator `?:` if `TRUE` is `1` and `FALSE` is `0`.)

Answer (score 1):

With `myArray` being some generic integer type, there's really no other way than to iterate across all items in the array, if TRUE then set bit `i` with `bitfield |= 1u << i;`.