# Set Last Element of boolean array to as Most Significant Bit within an Bitfield

Tags: c, bit-fields

let's suppose I have an Boolean array with 7 elements like

```
boolean myArray = {1,0,1,1,1,0,1}
```

this array I want to represent within an bitfield:

```
uint8 myBitfieldofmyArray;
```

It is important that the last element of array is set as the Most Significant Bit in *myBitfieldofmyArray*.
The Least Significant Bit (Bit 0) is not considered and is by default always 0.

With the following solution the 1.element is set as the Most Significant Bit:

```
uint8_t myBitfieldofmyArray= 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    myBitfieldofmyArray|= myArray[i] ? 1 : 0;
    myBitfieldofmyArray<<= 1;
}
```

How to adapt it so that the last element is set as the Most Significant Bit?

The Solution above was taken from:
[Pushing boolean values of an array to uint8 bitfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59071101/pushing-boolean-values-of-an-array-to-uint8-bitfield?noredirect=1#comment104387109_59071101)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "reverse loop":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() {
    bool myArray[7] = {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0};

    uint8_t myBitfieldofmyArray= 0;
    for (int i = 6; i >= 0; --i) {
        myBitfieldofmyArray |= myArray[i];
        myBitfieldofmyArray <<= 1;
    }

    printf("%d\n", myBitfieldofmyArray);    
}
```

`bool`s evaluate to either 0 or 1, so I think the ternary `? 1 : 0` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to store your bitfield starting from the MSB you can change your loop to:

```c
for(int i=0; i<7; ++i) 
   myBitfieldofmyArray |= (myArray[i]<<(7-i))
```

That being said, are you sure you want to need bitfields and not int/bool arrays?.

If you have 256 field storing them in int/bool array will take 1KB, and 32B with a bitfield.

So you gain less than 1KB by using a bitfield but you lose compactness, your code gets more complex and each read/write requires extra computation to get the right bit to set/clear so you lose performances (you can check the assembly code).

Thus, unless you have good reasons to use a bitfields (for exemple sending it through the network) you should definitely avoid them.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to use two counters to loop shifting the bits from the array starting at `array[0]` to the bit in your `uint8` starting with the MSB and incrementing the array index while decrementing the bit position, e.g.

```
    uint8_t myBitfieldofmyArray = 0, i = 7, j = 0;

    while (i--)
        myBitfieldofmyArray |= myArray[j++] << (i + 1);
```

**Result**

The bits of `myBitfieldofmyArray` are `10111010`